# .val() não funciona na tag textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, textarea, selected-option

Eu estou pegando um dado que está em um atributo da minha select-option (data-observacao), até aí tudo bem, entretanto quando eu tento passar esse valor para o meu textarea o valor não é impresso, apenas no console, alguém sabe me explicar o porquê disso? 
Segue o código:

```
 <select name="modelo" id="modelo" class="form-control">
   <option value="" selected disabled>Selecione</option>
   @foreach($modelos as $modelo)
    <option value="{{ $modelo->id }}" data-observacao="{{ $modelo->corpo}}"> {{ $modelo->titulo }} 
    </option>
   @endforeach
 </select>

 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 mt-3" id="div-observacao">
  <label for="">Observação</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="observacao" id="observacao" rows="3"></textarea>
 </div>
```

```
function removeTag(dataObservacao){
    dataObservacao = dataObservacao.replace("<p>","");
    dataObservacao = dataObservacao.replace("</p>","");
    return dataObservacao;

};

$("#modelo").on("change", function (event) { 
    let dataObservacao = $("#modelo").find("option:selected").data("observacao");
    dataObservacao = removeTag(dataObservacao);
    console.log(dataObservacao);
    console.log($("textarea[name='observacao']").val(dataObservacao));
    $("textarea[name='observacao']").val(dataObservacao);

});
```

Comment: Aqui funcionou normal. Agora, já que o textarea tem um id, vc pode usar ele no seletor: `$("#observacao")` em vez de `$("textarea[name='observacao']")`.

Comment: Lembrando que o script deve estar no final do `body`... Veja este [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3wfk5eb1/) como funciona corretamente.

Comment: Concordo com o Sam. Se no console está imprimindo o valor e no campo não. Ele não está achando o objeto textarea[name=observacao]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O valor não está imprimindo porque o textarea não é um input, e sim um elemento, você não pode simplesmente setar um `$('textarea').val();` você precisa trocar o que esta dentro de seu conteúdo dessa forma.

```js
//Arqivo JavaScript
$(document).ready(function(){

 var valor = "Algum texto somente para completar a text area";
    
        //Eu estou pegado elemento pelo ID do textarea que eh #alpha
 $('#alpha').text(valor);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<textarea id="alpha"></textarea>
```

**Pessoal do Stack Overflow Brasil...**

parem de negativar perguntas que vocês não conseguem responder, tenha mais paciência com quem esta aprendendo.

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: Você pode fechar este tópico avaliando essa resposta como correta. Que bom que funcionou.